# 遅いファイル出力処理でのプログレスバーの表示がうまくいかない

Tags: swift3

ファイルを出力してUIActivityViewController経由で転送する、という処理があります。
ファイルの元データを加工する処理を追加したのですが、この処理が遅くプログレスバーを表示させようと、現在苦戦しています。お知恵をお貸しください。

想定している動作は、
ボタンをタップ
->プログレスバーを載せたUIViewの子クラスが表示され、ファイルの加工処理開始。
->加工が完了したらプログレスバーの表示が100％になる。
->ファイルを出力。
->UIActivityViewControllerが表示される。
というものなのですが、
現状ではボタンタップ後、数秒経ってからプログレスバーが表示され、ほぼ同時にUIActivityViewControllerが表示されてしまいます。＞＜;

GCDを組み込んでみたりしたのですが(★の箇所)動作も理解もいまいちな状態です。
コードを以下に記します。
お手数ではありますが、どのように直したら良いかお教え頂けますと大変助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```
class MyClass: UITableViewController {

    fileprivate var _viewProgress: MyProgressView!
    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var btnAction: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //プレグレスバーを載せたビューを準備
        _viewProgress = MyProgressView() //(UIViewの子クラス)
        _viewProgress.isHidden = true
        self.view.addSubview(_viewProgress)
    }

    /// ボタン押下時処理
    @IBAction func btnAction_Tap(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        //プログレスバーを表示
        _viewProgress.setProgress(0.0)
        //_viewProgress.isHidden = false
        _viewProgress.show()
        /*　追記 show関数の中身↓
            func show() {
            if let oya = self.superview {
                self.center = CGPoint(x: oya.frame.width / 2, y: oya.frame.height / 2) //中央に配置
                oya.bringSubview(toFront: self) //最前面に配置
            }
            self.isHidden = false
        */

        //ファイル作成
        createFile() //---(1)へ
    }

    /// (1) ファイル作成処理
    func createFile() {
        //ファイル出力
        let rs = getData() //---(2)へ
        let filePath: String = outputFile(rs) //tmpフォルダに出力

        //(出力成功)
        if filePath != "" {
            let file = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            let handler: ((Bool) -> Void) = { [unowned self] (completed) in
                if completed == true {
                    print("処理完了")
                }
                self._viewProgress.dismiss()
            }
            //ダイアログ(UIActivityViewController)を表示
            showDialog(self, activityItems: [file as AnyObject], handler: handler)

        //(出力失敗)
        } else {
            //〜エラーメッセージ表示〜
        }
    }

    /// (2) データ加工処理
    func getData() -> [[String : String]] {
        //加工元のレコードセットを取得
        var rs: [[String : String]] = getOrgData()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).sync { //---★
            //ループしてレコードを1行ずつ処理
            for i in 0 ..< rs.count {
                //進捗表示
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in //---★
                    self._viewProgress.setProgress(Float(i + 1) / Float(rs.count))
                }

                var data = rs[i]
                //〜データの加工をゴリゴリ〜
                rs[i] = data
            }
        }
        return rs
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あなたのコードでせっかく書いたプログレスバー更新処理がうまくいかないのはこの部分のせいです。

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).sync { //---★
```

`sync`メソッドは呼び出し側のスレッド(今の場合メインスレッド)をブロックしてしまい、せっかく並行処理可能な`global`キューで実行しても、`DispatchQueue.main.async {...}`のところでメインキューに入れられた`self._viewProgress.setProgress(Float(i + 1) / Float(rs.count))`は、ずっとメインキューの中で順番待ち、あなたのコードで言うと`btnAction_Tap(_:)`の処理が完了するまで実行されません。

メインキューで行わなければいけない処理をブロックしないようにするためには、非同期処理を使って、「この部分は後で」あるいは「この部分は裏で(非同期に並列して)」と言うことだけ指定したら、さっさと`btnAction_Tap(_:)`を終了しないといけません。

言葉で言うと大変なことをさせられるように見えるかもしれませんが、あなたのコードの場合、典型的な定石通りの完了ハンドラーを使うパターンに簡単に書き換えられます。

(質問文中には説明されていないメソッド等があるので、若干修正しないと使えないかもしれません。)

```
/// ボタン押下時処理
@IBAction func btnAction_Tap(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    //プログレスバーを表示
    _viewProgress.setProgress(0.0)
    _viewProgress.isHidden = false

    //ファイル作成
    createFile() //---(1)へ
    //下に書いた理由と同じで、ここに何か処理を書くと、完了ハンドラーより先に実行されてしまう
}

/// (1) ファイル作成処理
func createFile() {
    //ファイル出力
    getData{ rs in //---(2)へ <-- 非同期処理の結果は戻り値で受け取ろうとせず、クロージャーで拾う
        let filePath: String = self.outputFile(rs) //tmpフォルダに出力

        //(出力成功)
        if filePath != "" {
            let file = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            let handler: ((Bool) -> Void) = { completed in
                if completed {
                    print("処理完了")
                }
                self._viewProgress.dismiss()
            }
            //ダイアログ(UIActivityViewController)を表示
            self.showDialog(self, activityItems: [file as AnyObject], handler: handler)

        //(出力失敗)
        } else {
            //〜エラーメッセージ表示〜
        }
    } //<- 「この部分(完了ハンドラー)は後で」(処理完了後に)実行するのを登録されるだけで`getData(completion:)`はすぐに終了する
    //従ってこの部分にコードを書いてしまうと完了ハンドラーより先に実行されてしまうので注意
}

/// (2) データ加工処理
func getData(completion: @escaping ([[String : String]])->Void) {
    //加工元のレコードセットを取得
    var rs: [[String : String]] = getOrgData()

    DispatchQueue.global().async { //<- ここで同期メソッドを呼んでは意味がない、必ず`async`を使う
        //ループしてレコードを1行ずつ処理
        for i in 0 ..< rs.count {
            //進捗表示
            DispatchQueue.main.async {//<- いくらここでメインキューに処理を入れてもメインキューが停止中だと意味がない
                self._viewProgress.setProgress(Float(i + 1) / Float(rs.count))
            }

            var data = rs[i]
            //〜データの加工をゴリゴリ〜
            rs[i] = data
        }
        completion(rs)  //<- 非同期処理の結果は戻り値にせずに完了ハンドラーに渡すというのが定石の一つ
    } //<- 「この部分は裏で」実行するよう登録されるだけで`DispatchQueue.global().async`自体はすぐに終了する
}
```

---

ちなみにあなたのコードの使い方では`[unowned self]`は不要(循環参照になる心配はない)なので、省かせてもらっています。どんな場合に「循環参照になる心配はない」のかがよくわからないのであれば`[unowned self]`ではなく`[weak self]`を使った方がいいでしょう。`unowned`は使い方を間違えるとアプリが簡単にクラッシュしてしまいます。

コメントには他にも色々書いていますが、とりあえずあなたのコードに当てはめて動きを確かめてもらってから意味を考えた方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: ご提示いただいたコードを組み込みましたところ、うまくいきました！丁寧な解説に感謝です。<(_ _)>　ボタンタップ直後にプログレスビューを表示させている箇所なのですが、表示されるまでに1秒ほどかかっています。可能であれば時間を短縮したいと考えていますが、可能でしょうか？

Comment: 質問文内のコードに加筆しました。想定の動きを実現できてやりきった感でいっぱいなのですが^^、実機でのビューの表示の遅延が気になっています。
`_viewProgress.isHidden = false`の箇所では実際はshow()関数を呼び出し、関数内でビューの位置の調整とisHiddenの設定を行っています。前後にprint出力を入れて確認してみましたが、すぐに実行されてはいるようで、重い処理ではなさそうです。ですが、シミュレーターでは問題ないのですが、実機のiPhone5(iOS8.4)とiPadmini(iOS10.1.1)では1秒程度の間があり、また押し方によってはUIBarButtonItemの色が変わらないので、連打されないように対策したいと考えています。間の原因が想像もつかないのですが、何かあればご指摘いただけますと嬉しいです。

Comment: @花の命は短い さん、追記された`show()`関数の中身を見る限り特に重い処理には見えません。気にするとしたら、「実際のUIの更新は`btnAction_Tap(_:)`のようなアクションメソッドが終了してから起こる」と言うことでしょうか。例えば`//加工元のレコードセットを取得` `var rs: [[String : String]] = getOrgData()`は並列処理スレッドの中ではなく、メインスレッドのの中で実行されますから、それに時間がかかると`createFile()`の終了までに時間がかかる⇒`btnAction_Tap(_:)`終了までに時間がかかる⇒プログレスバーの表示が遅れる、と言うことになります。`var rs: [[String : String]] = getOrgData()`の処理を`DispatchQueue.global().async {...}`の内側に入れると言ったことから試してみてください。

Comment: Le Pere d'OO様、いえ、きちんと想定した通りの順番で表示されています。ただ最初のビューの表示に一呼吸ある感じなのです。
ご提示の方法を試してみました。完璧でした。`va‌​r rs: [[String : String]] = getOrgData()`の処理を`DispatchQueue.global().async`の中にいれて、この行の前後でprint出力してみましたところ、速度的にまさにこれが問題だったようです。自身で気づかずお恥ずかしいですが、今現在は、ボタンタップでパッとビューが表示され、抽出、プログレスバーが進んで消えて、アラートビューが表示される、という完璧な動作をしています。数日苦戦しておりましたので大変助かりました。ありがとうございました。<(_ _)>

Comment: 解決につなげられたようで良かったです。「順序」については「UIの更新が実際に行われるのは、今のメインスレッドの処理が終わってから」と言うことを頭に入れておけばそのうちご理解いただけると思います。今回あなたが調べられた手法は、重いファイルの読み書き、非同期でしか実行できない通信処理等々いろいろな場所に応用可能です。良いアプリを。

Comment: Le Pere d'OO 様、根気よく教えていただき頭があがりません。(私の前のコメントが少しおかしかったです。失礼いたしました。)
まだまだ完璧に理解できたとはいえませんが、とても勉強になりました。いずれすんなり理解できる時が来るような気がしてきました^^
`[unowned self]`についてもよく理解せず使用していましたので、今全コードを見直しております。ご指摘ありがとうございました！